# How to POST Feedback on the basis of access token

Tags: android, react-native, post

I am trying to use my POST feedback API but I think I am lacking my logic somewhere due to which feedback is not recorded in my database. According to my system flow, only the logged in user can post a feedback which is working fine. But when I am trying to input a feedback and trying to submit nothing happens.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Modal,
    TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { Button, Paragraph, Wrapper } from '../components';
import { baseStyle, images, theme, routes } from '../config';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';


export const Reviews = ({ route }) => {
    const {userInfo} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigation = useNavigation();


    const [isModalVisible, setisModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const { item } = route.params;
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState();


    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
    const [FeedbackInfo, setFeedbackinfo] = useState({});
    const handleSubmit = () =>{
    console.log('Submitted Feedback: ',inputText);
    setisModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
}

    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://7a9f-119-157-88-43.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`)
            .then(response => {
                setResponseData(response.data.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, [item]);


    axios.post (`https://7a9f-119-157-88-43.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`, {
        inputText
    }).then(res => {
        let FeedbackInfo = res.data;
        setFeedbackinfo(FeedbackInfo);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('FeedbackInfo', JSON.stringify(FeedbackInfo));
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(FeedbackInfo);

    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(`feedback error ${e}`);
        setIsLoading(false);
    });

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <View style={styles.header} >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Image source={images.back} style={styles.backIcon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                < Text style={styles.headerText} > Reviews </Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.review} >
                {responseData &&
                    responseData.length > 0 &&
                    responseData.map((item) => (
                        <View style={styles.reviewContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.flex} >
                                <Paragraph style={styles.reviewer} > {item.name} </Paragraph>
                            </View>
                            <Paragraph>
                                {item.feedback_desc}
                            </Paragraph>
                        </View>
                    ))
                }
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.footer} >
                <TouchableOpacity>
                <Button onPress={userInfo.data
                        ?
                        (() => setisModalVisible(true))
                        :
                        navigation.navigate(routes.LOGIN, { item: item })}> Post a review </Button>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <Modal 
             transparent={true}
             animationType='slide'
             visible={isModalVisible}
             >
                <View style ={styles.reviewContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder='Enter Feedback'
                    onChangeText={setInputText}
                    value={inputText}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.Button}>
                        <Button Submit  onPress={() => handleSubmit}/>
                        <Button Close onPress={() => setisModalVisible(false)}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>    
        </Wrapper>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: baseStyle.marginBottom(32),
        paddingHorizontal: baseStyle.paddingHorizontal(15),
    },
    backIcon: {
        width: baseStyle.width(36),
        height: baseStyle.height(36),
    },
    headerText: {
        fontFamily: theme.font.bold,
        fontSize: baseStyle.fontSize(16),
        lineHeight: baseStyle.lineHeight(19),
        color: theme.colors.black,
        marginLeft: baseStyle.marginLeft(75),
    },
    review: {
        paddingHorizontal: baseStyle.paddingHorizontal(15),
    },
    reviewContainer: {
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.lightGrey,
        paddingVertical: baseStyle.paddingVertical(15),
        paddingHorizontal: baseStyle.paddingHorizontal(15),
        borderRadius: baseStyle.borderRadius(16),
        marginBottom: baseStyle.marginBottom(15),
    },
    flex: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' },
    reviewer: {
        opacity: 1,
        fontFamily: theme.font.bold,
        marginBottom: baseStyle.marginBottom(10),
    },
    starIcon: {
        width: baseStyle.width(15),
        height: baseStyle.height(15),
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
    date: { marginTop: baseStyle.marginTop(10) },
    footer: {
        borderTopLeftRadius: baseStyle.borderTopLeftRadius(32),
        borderTopRightRadius: baseStyle.borderTopRightRadius(32),
        paddingVertical: baseStyle.paddingVertical(18),
        paddingHorizontal: baseStyle.paddingHorizontal(18),
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: -5,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        elevation: 5,
        shadowColor: theme.colors.silver,
        shadowRadius: 6,
    },
});
```

Comment: typo - you have `<Button Submit  onPress={() => handleSubmit}/>`.  Should be `<Button Submit  onPress={() => handleSubmit()}/>` or `<Button Submit  onPress={handleSubmit}/>`

Comment: I think this is not the solution to my problem? It's just an typo advice.

Comment: it is the solution to your problem - you are not calling the function